# Weekday(date) compare with current date weekday

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (`users`) 
  JOIN `artistprofiles` AS art 
    ON `art`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE WEEKDAY(users.date_created) = 'WEEKDAY(WEEKDAY(NOW()))' 
  AND `users`.`status_enum` = 'aproved' 
  AND `users`.`status` = 1 
ORDER BY `users`.`email_process` DESC
```

what is the problem with this query . it gives me wrong result

Comment: try this `WEEKDAY(users.date_created) = WEEKDAY(NOW())` without single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
WHERE WEEKDAY(users.date_created) = 'WEEKDAY(WEEKDAY(NOW()))'
```

**Example**:

```
select 
    @wd:=WEEKDAY(curdate()) wd, 
    @str:='WEEKDAY(WEEKDAY(NOW()))' str, 
    @wd=@str,
    @wd=WEEKDAY( now() ) ;
```

**Results**:

```
+------+-------------------------+----------+----------------------+
| wd   | str                     | @wd=@str | @wd=WEEKDAY( now() ) |
+------+-------------------------+----------+----------------------+
|    2 | WEEKDAY(WEEKDAY(NOW())) |        0 |                    1 |
+------+-------------------------+----------+----------------------+
```

In your query you are comparing week day value with a *literal* string `'WEEKDAY(WEEKDAY(NOW()))'`. As they do not match, it returns a *false* and hence you see wrong results.

To check if the week day of the column with week day of now, then

**Change**:

```
WHERE WEEKDAY(users.date_created) = 'WEEKDAY(WEEKDAY(NOW()))'
```

**To**:

```
WHERE WEEKDAY(users.date_created) = WEEKDAY( NOW() )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) JOIN `artistprofiles` AS art ON `art`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` WHERE WEEKDAY(users.date_created) = WEEKDAY(NOW()) AND `users`.`status_enum` = 'aproved' AND `users`.`status` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`email_process` desc
```

The `'` make it a string. So you don't get the weekday.

You might want to read this: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: i am writing it in codeigniter which automatically puts '' on it how can i remove it